# Git reset ¿que borra exactamente?

Tags: git

Tengo una duda con "git reset". Si por ejemplo tengo 3 commit fase1, fase2 y fase3 cuando hago `git reset --soft fase2` ¿por que desaparece fase 3 y no fase2? Cuando hago git log solo veo fase1 y fase2. Si hay alguna duda de lo que digo vean por favor este video:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vH9pkFf1D7M&feature=youtu.be
```

en el minuto 14:36 que ocurre algo similar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`git reset` no borra realmente nada. Lo que hace es retroceder la rama en la que estás hasta el commit que le indiques.

Los sucesivos cambios (commits) por los que el repositorio va pasando pueden visualizarse como un grafo en el que cada nodo es un commit, y cada línea es una referencia al *commit* anterior (el padre).

En una historia lineal, el grafo es también una línea. Por ejemplo el caso del vídeo que enlazas, que sólo tiene 3 commits

[image: Grafo]

En otras historias más complicadas puede haber ramificaciones (dos o más nodos que tienen el mismo padre) y mezclas (un nodo que tiene dos padres), como por ejemplo:

[image: Grafo compliado]

En este grafo se ve que hubo una bifurcación tras el primer commit `d463`. Una de las bifurcaciones dio lugar a varios *commit* (`ff89`, `721a`, `ae21`) y podría tratarse de una rama en la que aún se esté trabajando. La otra bifuración (`b703`) se bifurcó de nuevo a su vez, pero enseguida ambas bifurcaciones se reunieron en `1234` que sería un *commit* de tipo *merge*, y  la historia continúa por `cc80` que perfectamente podría ser otra rama en la que también se esté trabajando.

Git necesita información adicional para seguir el rastro de ramas y en cuál estamos trabajando. Es decir, cuando haces el comando `git commit` se creará un nodo nuevo pero ¿cuál será su padre?

Para eso utiliza una serie de "variables" por así llamarlas.

- Las ramas. Una rama es un nombre (por ejemplo `master` o `develop`) asignado por el usuario (salvo `master` que siempre existe de antemano) y que "apunta" a un commit concreto.

  Por ejemplo, sobre el grafo anterior, podemos suponer que el commit `cc80` es el último de la rama "master", mientras que el `ae21` es el último de otra rama que podemos llamar "prueba".

  Git tendría por tanto las "variables" `master` y `prueba` apuntando a los correspondientes commits así:

  [image: Ramas]
- La "variable" `HEAD` que "apunta" al commit en el que "estamos", por así decir. Es el commit que será el padre del siguiente que hagamos. La variable `HEAD` podría estar apuntando directamente a un commit, como en la figura siguiente:

  [image: Detached HEAD]

  (Este estado se llama *detached HEAD*)

  Pero lo más habitual es que `HEAD` no apunte directamente a un commit, sino indirectamente a través de una rama. Es decir, `HEAD` apunta a la "variable" `master` o a la "variable" `prueba`, por ejemplo así:

  [image: HEAD master]

Una vez hemos planteado el escenario de esta forma gráfica, es mucho más sencillo entender qué hacen las diferentes operaciones de `git`.

- `git checkout prueba`, cambia el valor de `HEAD` para que sea `prueba`. A la vez, cambia la carpeta de trabajo para que muestre lo mismo que había en el commit `ae21`. Si después haces `git checkout master`, `HEAD` volvería a cambiar de valor para ser `master` (y la carpeta de trabajo cambiaría de nuevo).
- `git add cosas` añade esas cosas al *stage* (almacén intermedio antes de un commit)
- `git commit` crea un nuevo commit con lo que había en el *stage*. El padre de ese commit será el señalado por `HEAD`. Si `HEAD` señalaba a una rama (por ejemplo `master`) se actualiza también el valor de la rama para que apunte al nuevo commit. Por ejemplo, en nuestra anterior figura un *commit* llevará a esta situación:

  [image: nuevo commit]

  donde `abcd` es el commit recién creado.
- `git log` muestra desde el commit señalado por `HEAD` hacia atrás, todos los commit que se vaya encontrando hasta llegar al primero. En el caso de la figura anterior por tanto `git log` mostará los commit `abcd`, `cc80`, `1234`, `df89`, `b703` y `d463` (`git log` tiene opciones para mostrar también *commits* que estén en otras ramas, pero no entraré en esto).

Y ahora por fin...

- `git reset`*`commit`* cambia el valor de la rama actual (digamos que es master) para que apunte al commit que le indiques. Por ejemplo, si tras la figura anterior haces `git reset 1234`, la nueva situación sería esta:

[image: Git reset]

Simplemente el valor de `master` (y por tanto `HEAD` que apuntaba a él) se ha movido a otro commit. No se ha borrado en realidad nada, pero si te fijas, el siguiente commit que se haga ahora tendría como padre a  `1234`. Creará por tanto una nueva bifurcación, y dejará "abandonada" la antigua que tenía los *commit* `cc80` y `abcd`. En ese sentido parece que esos commit se han borrado, pues cuando hagas `git log` no los verás.

Por otro lado `git reset`, además de modificar la rama (y el `HEAD`) también modifica el *stage*, cambiándolo por los contenidos del commit al que te has ido. Si quieres evitar eso, usas la opción `--soft`, que por tanto no modifica nada. En concreto `git reset` no modificará tampoco tu carpeta de trabajo, que seguirá mostrando lo mismo que había antes de que hicieras `reset`. Pero si le das la opción `--hard`, entonces sí la modificará, para que coincida con lo que había en el *commit* al que te has ido.

Comment: Gracias por esta extensa respuesta. Yo pensaba que un "reset --soft" eliminaba un commit en concreto pero veo que lo que en realidad hace es eliminar (no eliminar realmente sino retroceder) los commit hasta el que se indica en el comando.

Comment: @RicardoKra En realidad un commit no se puede eliminar. O si se puede es extraordinariamente difícil. Lo que si puedes es modificar los "punteros" (ramas y `HEAD`) para llevarlos a otra parte del grafo. Los commits que se quedan "sin referenciar" como consecuencia de esos movimientos, están como ocultos, pues no es posible volver a ellos si no recuerdas su hash. De hecho con el paso del tiempo `git` va eliminando commits "abandonados" de esta forma. Creo que el grafo ayuda a entender bien muchas cosas.